# how to send the location information collected to server using http request/response in windows phone 7 or 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Application which we are currently developing collects location information using Geolocator. I want to send this collected info to the server. Could anyone plz suggest some APIs or methods to do the same.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a web service to do it, or use Azure mobile services to write to an Azure database, or even use background file transfer to transfer the location in a file to your server